# Ошибка SSLError при загрузке библиотеки?

Tags: python, pycharm, pip, gdb

Пытаюсь загрузить библиотеку fdb выскакивает ошибка

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get loca
> l issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/fdb/
>
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/fdb/: There was a problem
> confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/fdb/ (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificatio error(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping ERROR: Could not find a version that
> satisfies the requirement fdb (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching
> distribution found for fdb

Понятно что ругается на сертификат, а где его взять и соответственно подгрузить?

Comment: А в браузере на том же компьютере https://pypi.org открывается?

Comment: @andreymal  открывается.

Comment: `pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install ...` - попробуйте так.

Comment: @user207200 спасибо помогло поставьте в ответ.